# Array in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, arrays

I have an array Newstr(20) When I fill it, I need to know how many of its indexes has been filled ? and find out the values.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to know how many of its indexes has been filled ?

Arrays don't keep that information.  They only know how many spots you allocated.  You have to track how many you assigned yourself.  More than that, if you're working with a collection where you don't know how many items there will be, arrays are really the wrong choice in the first place.  You should use a List(Of T) instead.

Comment: +1, List(Of T) will not limit you to the number of items to add in an array.

Comment: @Hans - not necessarily.  What if "nothing" is an allowed value? Or if it's a collection of value types?

Answer (score 0):

You could populate the array with a known string, then test for that string to see how many elements in your array are filled.

I would - however - suggest using an array list.  You can get the number of elements added to the list from the Count property.  This is the MSDN entry for [Array Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x4b0a97.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In order to find which of the elements have been filled, you can use a LINQ construction like this:

```
    Dim input() = New String() {"abc", "def", "ghi", "", Nothing}
    Dim output = input.Where(Function(i) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).ToArray
```

When you run this code, the output array will contain `"abc"`, `"def"` and `"ghi"`.
You can modify the selector of the `Where` to suit your preference if you're coding for a different type of array.

For instance the selector for `Integer?` will be:

```
input.Where(Function(i) (Not i Is Nothing) Or (i <> 0)).ToArray
```

Of course, you'll have to be coding in .NET 3.5+ in order to get access to LINQ.